# How to uncheck radio button javascript

Tags: javascript, xslt

I have the below radio button. When it is clicked it is not possible to clear the radio button.

the code is

```
<td class="Label">
<input class="Label" type="radio" name="reviewoptions_{@id}" value="other" onClick="reAssign({count(../bankguaranteedata)},document.lending.guaranteereviewoptions,this,{@id})">
<xsl:if test="guaranteereviewoptions/reviewoptions[@id='other']='checked'">
<xsl:attribute name="checked"/>
</xsl:if>
</input>Other</td>
```

is it possible that when its clicked again it will clear the radio button?

Comment: I suggest that you create a working example at http://jsbin.com/. Thats going to make it much easier to help.

Comment: created http://jsbin.com/oputew/1/

Comment: I think I'm just going to change it to a checkbox. makes more sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to de-select a radio button option in HTML, for some reasons why you might like to read this: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13511/why-is-it-impossible-to-deselect-html-radio-inputs

Comment: I think I'm just going to change it to a checkbox. makes more sense

Comment: I agree. Never the less, @muneebShabbirs example should work.

Answer (score 14):

i actually use this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].type == "radio") {
            elements[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution I've seen and it works perfectly.  It is also easy to modify if you need to do that.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 if($('#checkboxID').is(':checked')){
         $('#checkboxID').attr('checked', false);
    }else{
        $('#checkboxID').attr('checked', true);
}
```

this Code is using jquery

Comment: true and false represent check and unchecked

Answer (score 2):

you might try using a reset input.

```
<input type='reset' />
```

call reset for the form radio buttons are in.

```
document.getElementById("radiobuttonsform").reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only require one radio option, then a checkbox would be the way to go. However, It is totally possible to deselect a radio option by virtue of its design. All you need is another radio option. You could use a silent radio option. It's only function in the group is to deselect the other radio options. You can change the opacity and hide it, and activate it with a button, or by some other means. This also leaves the ability to reselect one of the open options. Since options are typically grouped, other form elements will not be affected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).